# IONIC 2 and the Splash screen long time

Tags: android, ios, angular, typescript, ionic2

I Developed many apps using ionic 2 and I had rough times with the splash screen. 
The splash screen takes a lot of time to disappear, I know this depends on the number of the plugins and the time each take to respond. So the problem is how can I delete the waiting of the splash screen or at least reduce it to only one second. Is there any kind of memory management configuration to add to the app so that it doesn't have to restart each time you open the app? I am open to more ideas if you have any.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You need to use right CLI for that. Use below one:

debug mode: This CLI supports AOT

```
ionic cordova run android --prod --device
```

release mode:

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

You can see http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/build/

Answer (score 1):

Build with option --prod. Note that it's longer than 1 second. Depends on hardware, app...

Answer (score 1):

There's some things you can do to lower the time it takes the app to fully load so the splash screen goes off early.

As said by Nguyen building an app with `--prod` flag (`ionic cordova build android --prod`) can help you. When building in production ionic do some additional steps like optimizing js, minifying css, minifying js and aot (ahead of time) architecture.

These can also be used with a normal building in case you want to test something in development mode, using flags like `--minifyjs`, `--minifycss`, `--optimizejs`, `--aot`.

Another thing you can do is using `enableProdMode()` so when angular builds it'll turn off some checkings and assertions from the framework. To do this in your `app.ts` file inside `app` folder do

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

enableProdMode();
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Does building with --prod mode automatically call enableProdMode() once the app is opened ?